# Minim of the even elements of the matrix and the maximum of the prime elements

Tags: matrix, visual-c++, primes

I have to calculateand then display in OOP of C++ 
Minimum of the even elements of the matrix and the maximum of the prime elements

As i made up my code
My problem is that i have no idea how to make so that the max value from a matrix to be a prime number and I have no clue if I should work with a for( ) and then use a if (value%i==0) or if there can be a better method.

````
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class matrix3
{
    int a[10][10], b[10][10], c[10][10], d[10][10], e[10][10], f[10][10], x, y, i, j, l1,l2,max, max2 = 0, min = 0, save, c1, c2;

public:
    void values();
    void transpose();
    void sum();
    void diff();
    void linie();
    void coloana();
    void minimul_elementelor_pare();
    void maximul_elementelor_prime();

};

void matrix3::values()
{
    cout << "Enter the rows   "; cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter the columns   "; cin >> y;
    cout << "Enter elements of first matrix\n\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= y; j++)
        {
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Enter elements of second matrix\n\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= y; j++)
        {
            cin >> c[i][j];
        }
    }
}
void matrix3::sum()
{
    cout << "Sum of Matrices 1 and 2 is\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= y; j++)
        {
            e[i][j] = a[i][j] + c[i][j];
            cout << e[i][j] << "";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
void matrix3::diff()

{
    cout << "Difference of Matrices 1 and 2 (1-2) is\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= y; j++)
        {
            f[i][j] = a[i][j] - c[i][j];
            cout << f[i][j] << "";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void matrix3::transpose()
{
    cout << "transpose of the matrix is\n";

    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= y; j++)
        {
            b[i][j] = a[j][i];
            cout << b[i][j] << "";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Transpose of the second matrix is\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= y; j++)
        {
            d[i][j] = c[j][i];
            cout << b[i][j] << "";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }   
}

void matrix3::coloana()
{
    cout << "test is\n";
    cout << "\n Numerele coloanelor care doriti sa le interschimbati";
    cout << "\n c1: ";cin >> c1;
    cout << "\n c2: ";cin >> c2;
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
       save = a[i][c1];
        a[i][c1] = a[i][c2];
        a[i][c2] = save;
    }
    for (i = 1;i <= x;i++) {
        for (j = 1;j <= y;j++) {

            cout << a[i][j] << " ";


        }
        cout << endl;

    }

}
void matrix3::linie()
{
    cout << "test is\n";
    cout << "\n Numerele coloanelor care doriti sa le interschimbati";
    cout << "\n l1: ";cin >> l1;
    cout << "\n l2: ";cin >> l2;
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        save = a[l1][j];
        a[l1][j] = a[l2][j];
        a[l2][j] = save;
    }
    for (i = 1;i <= x;i++) {
        for (j = 1;j <= y;j++) {

            cout << a[i][j] << " ";


        }
        cout << endl;

    }

}

void matrix3::minimul_elementelor_pare()
{
    cout << "Minimul Elementelor Pare";
    for (i = 1;i <= x;i++)
    {
        if (x % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (a[i][j] < min)
                min = a[i][j];
        }
            min++;


    }
    cout << " " << min;
}

void matrix3::maximul_elementelor_prime()
{
    cout << "max matrice" << endl;

    max=a[1][1];
    for (i = 1;i <= x/2;i++)
    {       
        for (j = 1;j <= y/2;j++)
             if (x%i != 0 && max < a[i][j])
                max = a[i][j];
        }
        cout << " maximul din matrice este " << max;



}


int main()
{
    int input;
    char ch;
    matrix3 m;
    m.values();
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter your choice\n";
        cout << " 1. Sum of 1 and 2\n" << " 2. Difference of 1 and 2\n" << " 3. Transpose of both 1 amd 2\n" << "4. Linii\n" << "5. Minim\n" << "6.Linie\n"<<"7. Maxim\n";
        cin >> input;
        switch (input)
        {
        case 1:
            m.sum();
            break;

        case 2:
            m.diff();
            break;

        case 3:
            m.transpose();
            break;
        case 4:
            m.coloana();
            break;
        case 5:
            m.coloana();
            break;
        case 6:
            m.minimul_elementelor_pare();
            break;
        case 7:
            m.maximul_elementelor_prime();
        }
        cout << "\nDo another y/n?\n";
        cin >> ch;
    } while (ch != 'n');
    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Does the maximum value in the whole matrix have to be a prime number or can it be a composite number?  The largest prime element in the matrix might be smaller than a composite maximum.

Comment: So the maximum value has to be a prime number